# Using a user defined function inside of another function with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following function defined in the .m file:

```
- (float) findRate:(CGPoint *) point From:(CGPoint *) spriteloc {

int xdist;
if (point > spriteloc) {
    xdist = point->x - spriteloc->x;
}
if (point < spriteloc) {
    xdist = spriteloc->x - point->x;
}

// v=d/t  t = d*v
float travelTime = xdist * 2; // 2 what? idk...
return travelTime;

}
```

And I have:

```
- (float) findRate:(CGPoint *) point From:(CGPoint *) spriteloc;
```

in the .h file.

I go to the init (.m file) function I attempt to call

```
float rate = [findRate:point1 From:point2];
```

It returns the error:  *Use of undeclared identifer 'findRate'*

I have the findRateFrom function defined before the init function.

I'm a bit new to Objective-C, and perhaps I'm just very confused.  But I thought that I could call my own functions within other functions assuming I defined them properly.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of a message send is the object receiving the message. In this case, the first thing in your message send brackets is `findRate`, so it believes you want to send the message `[findRate :point1 From:point2]`. Instead, the receiver should be `self`:

```
float rate = [self findRate:point1 From:point2];
```

(Incidentally, you don't normally capitalize the first word of a part of a message, so that would be `findRate:from:`, with a lowercase F.)

Comment: you missed the part where you put self in the the brackets